# Get audio option and switch them internally for calling application

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, voip

Anyone please ?  How we can get this option manually while developing VOIP based calling application?[image: H]

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

public class AlertSheet: NSObject {

```
public static func showActionSheet(_ actions: [AlertSheetModel], _ title: String,comletion: @escaping (_ action: AlertSheetModel, _ status: Bool) -> Void,onViewCotroller:UIViewController) {

    var style = UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad) {
        style = UIAlertController.Style.alert
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: style)
    for actionData in actions {
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: actionData.title
            , style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                comletion(actionData, true)
        })

        if let icon = actionData.image {
            action.setValue(icon, forKey: "image")
        }
        action.setValue(true, forKey: "checked")
        alert.addAction(action)
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { (UIAlertAction)in
    })

    alert.addAction(cancel)
    onViewCotroller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

open class AlertSheetModel {
    public var title: String
    public var key: String
    public var image: UIImage?
    public var isSelected: Bool = false
    public var object: Any?
    public init(_ title: String,_ key: String, _ image: UIImage?, _ isSelected: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.key = key
        self.isSelected = isSelected
        self.image = image
    }
}

class testActionSheet: UIViewController {

```
// initialize the image for following icon
let image1: UIImage = UIImage.init()
let image2: UIImage = UIImage.init()
let image3: UIImage =  UIImage.init()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showActionSheet()
}

private func showActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet1 = AlertSheetModel.init("iPhone", "iphone", image1, false)
    let actionSheet2 = AlertSheetModel.init("Speaker", "speaker", image2, false)
    let actionSheet3 = AlertSheetModel.init("Samsung Level U", "samsung", image3, true)

    AlertSheet.showActionSheet([actionSheet1,actionSheet2,actionSheet3], "", comletion:  { (sharedClick: AlertSheetModel, success) in

        if sharedClick.key == "iphone" {
           // handle the click action of iphone button
        }else if sharedClick.key == "speaker" {
            // handle the click action of speaker button
        } else if sharedClick.key == "samsung" {
            // handle the click action of samsung button
        }else {
        }
    }, onViewCotroller: self)
}
```

}

Comment: please read my question carefully.

I need all audio routes for avaudiosession and display as you mention not static value.